# Makefile: Include a generated-on-demand file

Tags: makefile, make

For the record, I'm writing according to the *NEXT* - Version 5 of Single Unix Specification, which is Issue 8 if you count the days when it was named XPG. In this new standard, a few new already-common-place features are being added, such as delayed and immediate expansion macros, and re-making of include files. Parts of the proposed changes are available [here](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1325#c5087).

My **end-goal** is to include something generated by more complex scripts, and this is just me practicing. For example, I want to create a "make" prerequisite listing of C/C++ include files; Or I want to extract a list of contributors to my project, and put this list in the "make" target for documentations.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to include a file in the main Makefile, and this file is always generated on-demand whenever the build targets are requested to make (thus excluding auxiliary targets such as clean, install, etc.)

Here's my Makefile

```
.PHONY: all clean timestamping

all: main.c
    ${CC} -o main -D LIB_RET=1${lib_ret} main.c

clean:
    rm -f main include.mk time.stamp

all: timestamping

timestamping:
    date -u '+%Y-%m-%d T %H:%M:%S %Z' > time.stamp

time.stamp:; :

include.mk: time.stamp
    printf 'lib_ret='`date +%S` > include.mk

include include.mk
```

Here's "main.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){ return LIB_RET; }
```

I'm quite satisfied with the current form of it, but I'm sure suggests for improvements will be plenty. I'm mostly concerned about the portability of this Makefile on FOSS makes, such as GNU make and pmake.

One part I'm not satisified is that the commands for `timestamping` and `time.stamp` gets executed twice on the make supplied by the Xcode toolchains (which uses GNU Make version 3.81 as of Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18) 2022-12-27).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems strange to be writing a non-text file here (i.e. lacking a final newline):

> ```
>     printf 'lib_ret='`date +%S` > include.mk
> ```

I would have written it with a newline, using

```
     date +lib_ret=%S >$@
```

It's also strange that it depends on `time.stamp` but doesn't use that dependency.  It's like you intended

```
    date -d $(cat $<) +lib_ret=%S >$@
```

Or perhaps not have the `timestamping` and `time.stamp` targets at all (and have `.PHONY: include.mk` instead).

Instead of `all: main.c`, we could let the default rules build `main` from `main.c`:

```
CFLAGS += -DLIB_RET=1${lib_ret}
all: main
```

If we can assume GNU Make is available (and that's a good assumption these days), then we could simplify the entire Makefile to

```
.PHONY: main clean

main: CFLAGS += -DLIB_RET=$(shell date +1%S)

clean::
    $(RM) main
```

Even without GNU Make, we could use `$$(date +1%S)` in `CFLAGS`.

And I'd recommend including at least `-Wall -Wextra` when compiling C sources.

Be aware that the whole concept of including timestamps in your builds is something the free software community has made great efforts to eliminate in recent years in the pursuit of *reproducible builds*, so I strongly urge you to reconsider whether this is something you really should be doing at all.

Comment: The `timestamping` and the `time.stamp` target are intentional, `timestamping` is used to ensure the commands for `include.mk` are always executed, `time.stamp` (with the null command) is there to prevent Make from reporting non-existent prerequisite. My end-goal is to include something generated by more complex scripts, so although I thank you for the simplified Makefile, I'll have to stick with the premise in the question.

Comment: Also, GNU make seem to reject include files that're phony targets, so I did away with it.

Comment: You don't need `timestamping` to ensure that `include.mk`'s commands are always executed - that's what `.PHONY` is for.

Comment: Yeah, but when I last tried, GNU make seem to reject include files that're phony targets as I said *in my last comment*. Of course, if you can provide a fragment of Makefile that behaves differently from what I've been observing, you're answer will be more than valuable.

Comment: That's probably a sign that the rule needs a comment explaining why it's done like that.  Without the comment, any future maintainer is likely to make the same assumptions I did.